# Is it possible to save pose to model

Tags: armature

[image]

I am trying to position these arms for an FPS game, but every time I export it, delete the armature, or go into edit mode, it just switches back to this:

[image]

Is it possible to save the pose to the model so that they stay as they are in the top picture?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to apply the pose permanently and never change it again?

Comment: On right side of this page you see Related Q, your seems to me as duplication of few first. right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the shape of the object as deformed by the armature, what you can do is select the object being deformed, and go to the modifiers tab.
In the modifiers tab, you will see a modifier "Armature deform". Apply this modifier not as a shape key if you want to permanently keep the shape, and as a shape *key* if you want to toggle between the original shape, and it's deformed shape. From what I saw in your question, this should solve your problem.